# Are Time Machine backups completely fail proof?

Tags: macos, time-machine, software-update

During OS update, some people report that the update fails and turns the machine into a brick, forcing them to take it to Apple.

Fail proof: No matter what, you can revert back.

Can I trust Time Machine? There's no Apple service in this country.

2015 mbp 13" from 10.14 to latest stable, time machine backup files are on external device obviously

Comment: No computer system (well consumer system) is fail proof. You probably need 3 backups one is time machine - one is offsite e.g. in cloud and one other. TM is as reliable as most other software. However in this case if worried the disconnect the TM disk before and during the upgrade so TM can't be corrupted

Comment: That's obviously not my concern

Comment: You ask about Time Machine and I show how the upgrade can't corrupt it. So what is your question re time machine?

Comment: You cannot boot from a Time Machine backup anyway, so that shouldn't have anything to do with whether an upgrade succeeds or not. If you want to make bootable images of your Mac (including your data), you need an app like SuperDuper,

Comment: @PaulJ  If the update process turns the machine into a brick, SuperDuper would  replace everything in the disk including hidden partitions, boot partition and  anything else the update process screwed up. Is this correct?

Comment: The boot partition yes, that's what Time Machine doesn't cover. As for the rest... I don't know exactly. You should look it up and read its docs, and see if it fits your use case.

Comment: What everyone is saying is that *nothing is completely fail proof.* So you should have a TimeMachine backup, **and** a SuperDuper (or other) local backup as well. And if practical back up your Mac to a cloud service like Amazon, BackBlaze, etc. The only fail proof backup is having more than one backup. Preferably at least three.

Comment: Vtc because, based on the OP’s last comment the machine is already bricked and the OP now wants the tools…

Comment: @SolarMike Yep I want to prepare for the worst

Comment: Preparing for the worst is having Time Machine & a clone of the drive just before update. You also need to swap out the Time Machine drive right before upgrade & then use a new drive afterwards. Time Machine does not like going 'downhill' so once it's seen the new OS it no longer wants to go back to the old one. An additional caveat is that TM on Monterey uses APFS, on Mojave it was HFS+. The two are not interchangeable. For true, house-burns-down disaster protection, an off-site backup such as Backblaze is belt & braces.

Comment: @Tetsujin How do I clone the drive?

Comment: That would be a whole other question, or google 'cloning software mac'.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to what everyone is telling you about backups and failures in general. To address your question more directly, though: It is ALWAYS possible for an upgrade to brick your machine. The way this happens is during the **firmware update sequence**. A botched sequence and/or a buggy firmware image, either EFI or SMC, will render your machine instantly unbootable, and no amount of backups will help you. The ONLY way to make that machine boot again is to manually reflash the broken firmware, which requires special tools that you're very unlikely to have, and therefore must get a third party to help service your Mac.

The good news is that Apple goes to extensive lengths to prevent the above scenario, precisely for the reason that a bad firmware update could affect millions of customers and therefore also be catastrophically bad for Apple. That's why there are many firmware QA tests that have to get passed before any OS update is made available to the public. Testing comprises a significant percentage of the time that it takes Apple to release an update. The high risk of catastrophic failure is also why minor OS up***dates*** (as opposed to major OS up***grades***) introduce few new features and are instead focused on bug fixes and polish: Making fewer firmware changes reduces risk.

In your case,

> 2015 mbp 13" from 10.14 to latest stable

you are attempting to upgrade a relatively old machine from Mojave to, presumably, Monterey. This is a +3 **major** version point jump. Such a procedure, when you can't afford a failure, is **not recommended**.

A lot of code at all layers of the stack changes between major upgrades. This constantly leads to situations where Apple has to write migration-specific code that will take data (including nonvolatile, boot-critical data) stored using yesteryear's paradigm and convert it to a newer format.

Apple's upgrade process is most heavily tested for the most common use case, which is a +1 major version upgrade. There is a lot less test coverage given to big leaps like the one that you are taking. The chances that a migration will run into an unhandled corner case are significantly higher when you are leapfrogging 3 major versions.

The safer approach (beyond having your data backed up in multiple locations) is to do major OS upgrades one-by-one (i.e, *Mojave* -> *Catalina* -> *Big Sur* -> *Monterey*, rather than *Mojave* -> *Monterey*). Yes, this takes longer, but it reduces the risk that you're going to end up having to erase & restore from your backups (at best) or have a system that no longer boots (at worst).

Comment: This is the answer I needed, thanks. `The ONLY way to make that machine boot again is to manually reflash the broken firmware, which requires special tools` Can I get those tools somehow?

Comment: @HABALABALUCOMINGFORTHEBOOTY I can’t help you with that.

Comment: Do you know the names of those tools? Like what should I search on google?

Comment: If this machine is mission critical then taking it to an Apple Store might be the safest approach - at least they can't say "we can't help you because you did unauthorized <something something>" At this point you appear to be one wrong step away from losing all your data permanently. Not trying to scare you - what I am suggesting is what I would do in your position.At least ask for their official advice.

Comment: You mean going to Apple so they can update the machine?